# How to capture two separate group patterns with Regex?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have this pattern in over 10.000 places:

**11,1,2,0,0,**"*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,* **8 - 14.** *consectetur adipiscing elit.* **6 - 13.** *Aenean semper fermentum ipsum sed vehicula. In commodo sit amet libero et rhoncus. Cras vitae dapibus nisl. Mauris lacinia dui lacus, ut sodales massa congue vel. Donec at* **8 - 11.** *dapibus mi, ullamcorper porttitor orci. Nullam id dui nibh. Fusce est ante, viverra* **4 - 7.** *et cursus vel, scelerisque imperdiet massa. Donec sit amet nibh porttitor, tincidunt lorem in, maximus elit.*"

I need to capture all **11,1,2,0,0,** patterns at the beginning of the sentence **AND ALL** the **8 - 14.** patterns (they have different numbers between dashes - and before the dot .) throughout the sentence using `Regex`.

How do I do this?

I have tried `(^\d*,\d*,\d*,\d*,\d*)+(\d* - \d*\.)`

The desired output is:

```
11,1,2,0,0, 8 - 14. 6 - 13. 8 - 11. 4 - 7.
```

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: Why the down vote? It's a legit question.

Comment: What is your expected output/match? btw I'm not the the one who down voted.

Comment: Thanks. Added the output to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex alternation for 2 patterns:

```
\b((?:\d+,)+|\d+\s*-\s*\d+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dY8dX1/1)

Comment: Thanks anubhava! Works perfectly. You helped me a lot!

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks for your great help!